# How to remove .py from urls for pyservlet using jython

Tags: java, servlets, jython

I'm looking at the jython servlet tutorial and have got everything working. How do I make the url be

localhost:8080/jythondemo/JythonServlet1

instead of

localhost:8080/jythondemo/JythonServlet1.py

http://seanmcgrath.blogspot.com/JythonWebAppTutorialPart1.html

Here is the relevant part from web.xml

```
<web-app>      
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletTest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ServletTest</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.python.util.PyServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletTest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ServletTest</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I've also tried with

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It seems with the above changes pyservlet is getting the url JythonServlet1 but it does not know what to do with it. Here is the error message:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: I can't guess the name of the class from /.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/testjython3/JythonServlet1
org.python.util.PyServlet.createInstance(PyServlet.java:202)
org.python.util.PyServlet.loadServlet(PyServlet.java:188)
org.python.util.PyServlet.getServlet(PyServlet.java:178)
org.python.util.PyServlet.service(PyServlet.java:155)
```

Answer (score 2):

As noted by @Jigar there's a restriction in the actual Jython Servlet code. However, you may get around that issue by creating a simple URL translator. It consists in a Servlet that internally forwards the request to the Py Servlet.

Use the following code for **web.xml**:

```
<web-app>      
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AliasServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>juanal.AliasServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.python.util.PyServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AliasServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.py</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Create a new class, say, **juanal.AliasServlet**, with the following content:

```
package juanal;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class AliasServlet extends HttpServlet
{

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String URI = request.getRequestURI();
        String newURI = URI + ".py";
        getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(newURI).forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

So, for a URL like this: localhost:8080/jythondemo/**JythonServlet1**, it will internally forward the request to **JythonServlet1.py**

Comment: Where should this package file be placed in a tomcat setup in ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

After that every request will be served by `PyServlet`

Comment: I get the following error:javax.servlet.ServletException: I can't guess the name of the class from /org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/testjython/JythonServlet1
 org.python.util.PyServlet.createInstance(PyServlet.java:202)
 org.python.util.PyServlet.loadServlet(PyServlet.java:188)
 org.python.util.PyServlet.getServlet(PyServlet.java:178)
 org.python.util.PyServlet.service(PyServlet.java:155)

Comment: can you please update log in question it would be more readable

Comment: and yes it should be `/*` not just `/`

Comment: It seems that pyservlet can not figure out JythonServlet1 should be JythonServlet1.py
    
javax.servlet.ServletException: I can't guess the name of the class from

wtpwebapps/testjython3/JythonServlet1
    at org.python.util.PyServlet.createInstance(PyServlet.java:202)
    at org.python.util.PyServlet.loadServlet(PyServlet.java:188)
    at org.python.util.PyServlet.getServlet(PyServlet.java:178    
    at org.python.util.PyServlet.service(PyServlet.java:155)

Comment: can you please post your web.xml and stacktrace in your question

Comment: stackoverflow does not seem to like my stack traces and web.xml. Web.xml is exactly the same as http://seanmcgrath.blogspot.com/JythonWebAppTutorialPart1.html except that I replace *.py with /* on your suggestion

Comment: After making your change, It seems that pyservlet is getting the url ocalhost:8080/jythondemo/JythonServlet1 but does not know what to do with JythonServlet1

Comment: its `/*` updated . and I am asking you to edit your question Stackoverflow will allow you to edit your question

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is inherent to PyServlet.java. PyServlet uses regular expressions to find the name of the Python class to load based on the path of the request. The regular expression used is defined as follows (line 245 in my copy of the source):

```
private static final Pattern FIND_NAME = Pattern.compile("([^/]+)\\.py$");
```

Unfortunately, this regular expression will break if the input URL path doesn't contain a ".py" extension - this raises the error that you saw.  From line 200:

```
Matcher m = FIND_NAME.matcher(file.getName());
if (!m.find()) {
    throw new ServletException("I can't guess the name of the class from "
            + file.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Since `FIND_NAME` is defined as `private` and `final`, I don't see a good way to override this behavior by just subclassing PyServlet - I think you'll have to make a copy of PyServlet and redefine this behavior in a fresh class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to python. But if you have Apache, you could rewrite all .py URLs!

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record: @Juanal AliasServlet trick works nicely.
I just had to use `request.getServletPath()` instead of `getRequestURI()`.
(working with Eclipse)